# Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, direct2d, directwrite

[Main article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368152(v=VS.85).aspx) there is a [header file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371579(v=VS.85).aspx) and a [source file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371577(v=VS.85).aspx). After copying those two files and adding few headers:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1")
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <d2d1helper.h>
#include "SafeRelease.h"
```

//Safe realease file

```
template<class Interface>
inline void
SafeRelease(
    Interface **ppInterfaceToRelease
    )
{
    if (*ppInterfaceToRelease != NULL)
    {
        (*ppInterfaceToRelease)->Release();

        (*ppInterfaceToRelease) = NULL;
    }
}
```

when I'm trying to compile this project I'm getting an error:

**Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DWriteCreateFactory@12 referenced in function "private: long __thiscall SimpleText::CreateDeviceIndependentResources(void)" (?CreateDeviceIndependentResources@SimpleText@@AAEJXZ)**

Have no idea why. All? headers are included. Hopefuly some of you will be able to help with this.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you set up the path for the lib files and dll files for the specific include files ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to link to Dwrite.lib, which includes the implementation of DWriteCreateFactory

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368040(VS.85).aspx) for documentation. Requirements section at the bottom explains what you need to include and link to to use the function that the error refers to.

You could probably fix this by adding the line

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Dwrite")
```

Comment: Fixed for me when I added it just under the include for dwrite.h

Comment: This also fixed the same error for me (simply adding the #pragma line below the include) in a WinRT C++ component.

Answer (score 1):

After adding:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dwrite")
```

this code works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention Dwrite.lib in the list of libraries to be linked to your application.