# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol NtOpenFile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, nt-native-api

I am facing linker error with my code. I am trying to compile with Visual Studio command Prompt (2010) in Win-7 X64 bit m/c.
The error which i see are as below.

> dust2.obj
>
> dust2.obj : error LNK2019: **unresolved external symbol _NtOpenFile**@24 referenced
>   in function _main
>
> dust2.obj : error LNK2019: **unresolved external symbol _RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeStr**
>   ing@12 referenced in function _main
>
> dust2.obj : error LNK2019: **unresolved external symbol _RtlInitAnsiString**@8 refer
>   enced in function _main
>
> dust2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

The simplified version of my code is like this:

```
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <Winternl.h>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
        NTSTATUS Status;
        OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES Obja;
        HANDLE SourceFile;
        PUNICODE_STRING PathName=0;
        PANSI_STRING p_path=0;
        const char* ccp_path = "D:\\txt.txt";
        RtlInitAnsiString( p_path,ccp_path );
        RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString( PathName, p_path, true );
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;
        wprintf(L"%s", PathName->Buffer);
        InitializeObjectAttributes(
            &Obja,
            PathName,
            OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE,
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
        Status = NtOpenFile(
                     &SourceFile,
                     FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
                     &Obja,
                     &IoStatusBlock,
                     FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                     FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE | FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT | FILE_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT
        );  
        if(SourceFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
            printf("\nError: Could not open file\n");
            return 0;
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;

}
```

In another post in this forum the solution of these kind of problem was mention to include a [#pragma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297920/unresolved-external-symbol).

I tried this solution by adding #pragma like this

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll")
```

but on compilation i see another error that says "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ntdll.lib'".

I will much appreciate your help to resolve this problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions cannot be called directly because they belong to internal API and are not exposed through any of the libraries. You need to obtain addresses of these function using GetProcAddress.

For more information look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/calling-internal-apis).

Answer (score 30):

Can't let this question go *unanswered* like this. Because although the remark by Mladen is largely right for this particular native API, the whole topic *deserves* an in-depth discussion.

### Preliminary cautionary note

Up front I should note that in many many cases it is [neither desirable nor necessary to use one of the native API functions on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/calling-internal-apis). However, there are a few cases where the Win32 API doesn't provide the means to query information or even manipulate data and so on. One such case would be several of the information classes available for [`NtQueryInformationFile`/`ZwQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwqueryinformationfile).

One good example is the enumeration of alternate data streams on files and directories, which can be done using the Win32 API, in particular by using the backup APIs, but will require special privileges in that case. Not so if you resort to the native API. The same used to be true for hard links until Windows 2000, which introduced [`CreateHardLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createhardlinka) to the Win32 API. Although in this particular case if you knew your way around you could have used [`MoveFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) with `MOVEFILE_CREATE_HARDLINK` ever since it got introduced (although Microsoft *still* as of this writing marks it as *Reserved for future use* ... meh).

The canonical books about the native API are these two:

- *Windows NT/2000 Native API Reference, Gary Nebbett*
- *Undocumented Windows 2000 Secrets: A Programmer's Cookbook*, Sven B. Schreiber ([free version from the author's website here](https://web.archive.org/web/20081025194109/http://undocumented.rawol.com/))

... there are more, including one that discusses NT 4 and preceded Nebbett's book. But Nebbett's book used to start the hype around the native API, much like Hoglund's book started the hype around Windows rootkits. Not a reference regarding the Native API topic but still good:

- Windows Internals, Mark Russinovich et. al.

Check out this website for a huge number of native API functions "documented":

- http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/

**So remember:** the inherent risk when using these functions is that they go away in a future Windows version or their semantics change without prior notice. So be careful *when* you use them, *if* you use them.

On to glory ...

## How to call native API functions

Actually there are two ways to call these functions. Microsoft was forced to disclose some of the native API functions in one of the antitrust law suits some years ago. These were shoved into `winternl.h` of the SDK. Microsoft expresses it thus:

> The `NtOpenFile` documentation is provided for the sake of full API
> coverage. `NtOpenFile` is equivalent to the `ZwOpenFile` function
> documented in the DDK. For more information on the `ZwOpenFile` and
> related functions, go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/library. In the
> left-hand pane, click Windows Development, then click Driver
> Development Kit.

However, there is no accompanying `ntdll.lib` file in the SDK. Microsoft suggests you link those functions dynamically (second option below).

You have several options:

1. The most common is to do as you did. But the `ntdll.lib` import library is only part of the WDKs, not the DDKs.
2. Use `GetProcAddress` to find the function pointer and call it. `GetModuleHandle` is sufficient for the Win32 subsystem since every Win32 program *is guaranteed* to have loaded `ntdll.dll`.

### Method 1: `ntdll.lib`

If you have the DDK/WDK - for Driver Development Kit and [Windows Driver Kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) respectively - you get a full set of `ntdll.lib` files already. On my system (Windows 7 WDK 7600.16385.1):

```
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\amd64\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\ia64\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wlh\amd64\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wlh\i386\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wlh\ia64\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wnet\amd64\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wnet\i386\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wnet\ia64\ntdll.lib
C:\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\wxp\i386\ntdll.lib
```

#### Create your own makeshift `ntdll.lib`

Otherwise you have to generate `ntdll.lib` yourself from the output of `dumpbin` (or by other means that allow to parse the exports of the DLL) which you can then output into a module definition file from which you can build an export `.lib`. Sounds convoluted? Not so much, let's see ;)

Using Ero Carrera's [`pefile` Python module](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile), we can do this:

```
import os, re, sys
from os.path import basename, dirname, join, realpath
try:
    import pefile
except ImportError:
    try:
        sys.path.append(join(realpath(dirname(__file__)), "pefile"))
        import pefile
    except:
        raise

def main(pename):
    from pefile import PE
    print "Parsing %s" % pename
    pe = PE(pename)
    if not getattr(pe, "DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT", None):
        return "ERROR: given file has no exports."
    modname = basename(pename)
    libname = re.sub(r"(?i)^.*?([^\\/]+)\.(?:dll|exe|sys|ocx)$", r"\1.lib", modname)
    defname = libname.replace(".lib", ".def")
    print "Writing module definition file %s for %s" % (defname, modname)
    with open(defname, "w") as f: # want it to throw, no sophisticated error handling here
        print >>f, "LIBRARY %s\n" % (modname)
        print >>f, "EXPORTS"
        numexp = 0
        for exp in [x for x in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT.symbols if x.name]:
            numexp += 1
            print >>f, "\t%s" % (exp.name)
    print "Wrote %s with %d exports" % (defname, numexp)
    print "\n\nUse this to create the export lib:\n\tlib /def:%s /out:%s" % (defname, libname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("ERROR:\n\tSyntax: fakelib <dllfile>\n")
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1]))
```

A sample output of running this script (when named `fakelib.py`) would be:

```
> fakelib.py ntdll.dll
Parsing ntdll.dll
Writing module definition file ntdll.def for ntdll.dll
Wrote ntdll.def with 1984 exports


Use this to create the export lib:
        lib /def:ntdll.def /out:ntdll.lib
```

Then we run the command as given on the last line. It is even better to give the `/machine:` parameter, of course. This is left as an "exercise" (*cough* *cough*) to the reader. The output with VS 2012 will be:

```
> lib /def:ntdll.def /out:ntdll.lib
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 11.00.51106.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : warning LNK4068: /MACHINE not specified; defaulting to X86
   Creating library ntdll.lib and object ntdll.exp
```

Congratulations. You can now use the `ntdll.lib` created by Microsoft's own `lib.exe` to statically import from `ntdll.dll`, even without having the "real" (original) `.lib` on your system.

Adjust the path and file names to your needs and tastes.

#### When using MinGW

[Damon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572743/damon) pointed out in a comment that the toolchain included with MinGW contains a tool `gendef` that can do the job of above Python script and that the output can be fed to `dlltool`.

#### Issues

The above method works perfectly when targeting x64 (64-bit), but for x86 (32-bit) I have encountered linker errors at times.

The issue is that the name decoration for `__stdcall` differs between x64 and x86. The former doesn't really use the same `__stdcall` as x86 and therefore just prepends an underscore. However, the latter also appends a the number of arguments times `sizeof(void*)` (i.e. 4). So for one argument the decorated function name for a function `int __stdcall foo(int);` becomes `_foo@4`.

[This KB article from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131313) outlines a way to get around the issue.

### Method 2: dynamically imported, using `GetProcAddress`

Documentation in MSDN states (for `NtOpenFile`):

> Note that the DDK header file `Ntdef.h` is necessary for many constant
> definitions as well as the `InitializeObjectAttributes` macro. The
> associated import library, `Ntdll.lib` is also available in the DDK. You
> can also use the `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` functions to
> dynamically link to `Ntdll.dll`.

Declare a function type, e.g. here we declare the type `TFNNtOpenFile` suitable in your case:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI  *TFNNtOpenFile)(
  OUT PHANDLE FileHandle,
  IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
  IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
  OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
  IN ULONG ShareAccess,
  IN ULONG OpenOptions
);
```

... and then retrieve the function pointer and call it:

```
TFNNtOpenFile pfnNtOpenFile = (TFNNtOpenFile)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtOpenFile");
status = pfnNtOpenFile(...); // can't be bothered to type out all parameters ;)
```

an alternative way of retrieving the function pointer could be this one:

```
static NTSTATUS (NTAPI  *NtOpenFile)(
  OUT PHANDLE,
  IN ACCESS_MASK,
  IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
  OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK,
  IN ULONG,
  IN ULONG
);
(FARPROC)&NtOpenFile = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtOpenFile");
```

which could be condensed even further by using the preprocessor stringification operator (`#`). The choice is yours.

Comment: Slight addition to this excellent answer: If you are so unlucky as to use MinGW/MSYS (which neither has the import lib, nor an official tool), you can use `gendef` to produce a `.def` file which `dlltool` will read (using `-d` for specifying the def-file, and `-l` for telling it to create the import lib).

Comment: This should be marked as the Answer to this question. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm still getting unresolved external symbol after doing the python run. I ran pefile on \windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll because I'm compiling for x32. My previous solution was to add ordinals to the .def file: ZwQueryInformationProcess@20 .@1665

But this ordinal changes

When I get unresolved ex. sym. There is .@num after the func, if I add this .@num

It links, but using depend walker I see it actually tries to import ZwQueryInformationProcess@20 , and when I run the file I get:

The entry point RtlComputeCrc32@12 could not be located in the dynamic link library ntdll.dll. 
-
OK   
-

Comment: It seems like ntdll.lib is included in the Windows 10 SDK these days, at least I find it in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\<Platform>`?! Together with `#include <winternl.h>` it then becomes a no-brainer.

Comment: @klaustriendl: indeed, it does. Have you been able to verify that it is a full ntdll.lib and not one providing only a subset of the exported functions? Which exact SDK version are you referring to, btw?

Comment: @0xC0000022L I didn't verify whether it's a full ntdll.lib or only a subset, but it seems to offer the kind of publicly documented Nt* API (all the functions the OP mentioned are exported). As hidden in the path I am referring to SDK v10.0.14303.0, I'll see somewhen in the near future whether this is still true for newer SDKs.

Comment: @klaustriendl ntdll.lib doesn't contain full exports (Ki* and string routines) ref: https://github.com/dynamorio/dynamorio/issues/894

Comment: @MohdShahril not exactly sure what it is you're trying to say, but either way you should specify _which_ version of `ntdll.lib` you're referring to, as this matters. The "string routines" you seem to refer to are C runtime functions. They were never supposed to be used in the first place, so removing them seems a consistent change. Or perhaps you mean those from `strsafe.lib`?