# Is there an easy way to call native NT API?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2019, ntdll, nt-native-api

I am working with pretty old code that taps directly into NT API (`NtQueryDirectoryFile(..., FileBothDirectoryInformation)`, etc).

Methods that allow user-mode application to call these functions [are well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117763/6427477). In my case someone (ages ago) copy-pasted related DDK declarations (structs and functions) into separate header file and manually generated `ntdll.lib` to link against.

This works, but:

- having to do this manual work for every new function is not ideal
- there is potential of introducing a subtle bug (e.g. forgetting to enforce correct data alignment)
- (pretty large) `ntdll.lib` ends up being stored with source code

I wonder if there is better way to do it with newer SDK/DDK?

Notes:

- environment: VS2019 with `10.0.18362.0` Windows SDK
- I know about `winternl.h` -- alas, it doesn't contain all functions I need

Comment: *ntdll.lib* and *ntdllp.lib* (here exist also static linked c-runtime) was inside any WDK. not need build *ntdll.lib* yourself.  here no any problems. include *ntifs.h* with *windows.h* is more problematic, but also possible. key - include *ntifs.h* inside namespace. this not resolve all errors (especially with `/permissive-` compiler options - some definitions conflict. but anyway possible resolve and this

Comment: @RbMm I got sidetracked with another project. Thank you for advice! I'll try to follow it when I have some time and if it works -- post is as an answer.

Comment: If you only need `NtQueryDirectoryFile`, you can have it by `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, which takes `FileIdBothDirectoryInfo`. Some other APIs that were previously only available using NT API are now available with the usual API. Check out other `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` params and `SetFileInformationByHandle` params.